# what is regular expression means

Tags: regex

I want to understand what  regular expression means

```
(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$
```

Below is what I understand the expression to me. Can you confirm or explain?

`(?=^.{8,}$)` string should be 8 character or more

`((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))` string should consist of one number or one special character. What is the plus after W?

`(?![.\n])` Not sure what this part means.

`(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$` My understanding is that `$` means end of expression, so it's kinda confusing why there's a dot and an asterisk before it. Also why is there only one `$`? Shouldn't it have two: one `$` after `.*[A-Z]` and one after `.*[a-z]`? To say that this section is supposed to make sure that user typed one small and one capital letter?

I am using this code in html form for practice and it's working fine.

All together this regular should achieve this and it's doing it 
**UpperCase, LowerCase, Number/SpecialChar and min 8 Chars**

Edit: regex101.com  i am also trying to understand on this side as @ymonad said in comment

Comment: there's a good site: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex:

`(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$`

**Explanation:**

- `(?=^.{8,}$)` - [Positive Lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to validate that the test string has atleast 8 characters(except a new-line character) between the start and the end of string
- `(?=.*\d)` - [Positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to validate that the test string contains a digit
- `|` - OR
- `(?=.*\W+)` - [Positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to validate that the input string has atleast 1 or more non-Word characters which DO NOT fall in this range `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- `(?![.\n])` - a [Negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to validate that the input string does not have a newline character `\n` or a dot `.` at the current position
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - [Positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to validate that the input string has an Upper case letter `[A-Z]`
- `(?=.*[a-z])` - [Positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to validate that the input string has a lower case letter `[a-z]`
- `.*` - Until this point we were just validating our input string against various rules. Now, using `.*` we are matching 0+ occurrences of any character except a new line character
- `$` - asserts the end of the string

Also, as pointed out in the comments, [THIS SITE](https://regex101.com/r/YDUa08/1) can be a good start.

Comment: thanks for the answer do i really need this section `(?![.\n])` i am getting the impresssion that i dont

Comment: @user2860957 It depends on what you're actually trying to validate. I'm not sure why you'd need to check for newlines, but you may need to disallow `.`

Comment: Actually, it depends upon your requirements. This part is just validating that the current position should not be followed by a `.` or a `\n` i.e, newline character. I am assuming that if your current position is at the start of the string, it means that the 1st charcter should not be a `.` or a newline character.

Comment: thanks nah i dont need this line than, as i got this regex online, and i was trying to understand it, in this portion was driving me crazy, and my requirment was `UpperCase, LowerCase, Number/SpecialChar and min 8 Chars` and @EdwardMinnix as well.